# Hodge metric and complex variation of Hodge structures of weight 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be complex polarized variation of Hodge structurs of weight $1$ and rank $2$ on the punctured smooth curve $Y_{0}=Y\backslash S,$ with unipoten monodromies around points of $S$. We will suppose that the universal covering $\tilde {Y_{0}}$ of $Y_{0}$ is the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}.$ Let $p:\tilde{Y_{0}}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ be the lift of the period map. Let $\omega_{\mathbb{V}}$ be the metric on   $\tilde{Y_{0}}$ induced by the Hodge metric of the complex variation(i.e. of associated Hodge bundle.) Let $\omega_{H}$ be the metric on $\mathbb{H}$ . Let $\rho:\pi_1(Y_{0})\rightarrow SU(1,1)$  be the corresponding representation and $\Gamma=\text{Im}\rho.$ We will suppose that both metrics are $\Gamma$ invariant. Is there some numerical connection between $p^{*}\omega_H$ and the trace of the curvature of the Hodge metric?

Comment: you may see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.3839.pdf